# Install Ubuntu on a laptop running XP

Tags: laptop, dell, windows-xp

When I being to install Ubuntu, the only choices for the 'Desktop environment' are Ubuntu and all the other ...buntu(s). I don't see a choice for the laptop version. Is this normal?

I am trying to install Ubuntu for my Dell Laptop running XP.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. There is no special Ubuntu laptop version. Desktop and laptop use the same installation media. When you visit www.ubuntu.com to download Ubuntu, you are given a choice of Ubuntu releases using several different desktop environments. Any further customization that you want can be done after you finish installing Ubuntu.

Check the release notes of the release of Ubuntu that you want to download before you download it to make sure that your computer has the same or better hardware (CPU, RAM, etc.) than the minimum system requirements.